# Oracle service names with a minus sign (?)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Are there any reasons not to use minus signs/dashes/hyphens in Oracle service names?
DBMS_SERVICE, tnsping and sqlplus seem to be fine, but the documentation says **no**.

We are switching from Oracle **SIDs** to **service names**. Apparently, they can be longer than SIDs (64 chars instead of 8), and can contain a domain name (hence dots `.` and minus signs `-`). The documentation of DBMS_SERVICE says that `service_name` is limited to 64 characters, and `network_name` is limited to the **NET service_name character set** 
which is restricted to

```
[a...z] [A...Z] [0...9] _
```

So, what about dots and hyphens? Are they ok or not?

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_serv.htm#ARPLS68018
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/syntax.htm#NETRF175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle said no, only [a...z] [A...Z] [0...9] _